# Vlookup in excel returns NA

Tags: excel

I have an excel with 3 columns populated.

The scenario is I want to compare values from column `J` with `H` and return the result value from `F`. I wrote the `VLOOKUP` but its not returning the values.

Below pasted are the screenshots of this scenario:

```
VLOOKUP Formula used = =VLOOKUP(J1,$F:$H,1,FALSE)
```

[image]

Is there something wrong with the formula or is there any other way to do it?

Comment: Vlookup always checks the first Column in  lookup table - in your case it compares the J column with the F column and returns the value from F. If you want to compare with the column H you'll need to change the column order.

Comment: `VLOOKUP` only works when you're looking to the right. To find a value from the left-hand side of the key, use [`INDEX` and `MATCH`](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2014/08/13/excel-index-match-function-vlookup/).

Comment: I have tried changing column order.. still its not working .Will try INDEX and MATCH

Answer (score 1):

Using index match

```
=INDEX($F:$F, MATCH($J1,$H:$H, 0))
```

You can't look 'backwards' with VLOOKUP, and whilst it has its bonuses for situations like this always use `INDEX MATCH`

Answer (score 0):

You could try this `=INDIRECT("F" & MATCH(J1,$H:$H,0))`.

Comment: Thank you very much . It worked exactly like i wanted . :D